# Add bootstrap-toggle to JHipster (Angular 2+)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, jhipster

I would like to add a bootstrap add-on, namely [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) to a JHipster Project. The project consists of a `.css` and `.js` file and requires jquery.

Simply adding this to `index.html` works fine but feels hacky.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

I would like to take advantage of yarn and webpack. I tried adding a `vendor.css` to the content folder which imports the toggle css file, but that didn't seem to do anything:

```
@import 'node_modules/boostrap-toggle/css/bootstrap-toggle.css';
```

How can I add Bootstrap Toggle (or similar libraries) from my `node_modules` folder to the application?

Comment: @RahulSingh I think you linked to the wrong question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/q/45339209/2708210

Comment: My bad sorry. The answer of that question explains how to use third party css or js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually far simpler than both suggestions. All you need to do is mention the required resources in the `vendor.ts`. That includes javascript.

```
import '../content/scss/vendor.scss';
import '../content/css/vendor.css';
import 'path to js'
```

The `vendor.css` is similar to `vendor.scss`, but the import path is a bit different. Tilde denotes the `node_modules` folder, as far as I understand.

```
@import "~github-markdown-css/github-markdown.css";
```

And that is all. No meddling with `.angular-cli.json` or anything required.

Answer (score -1):

In angular 2+, If you create project using `@angular/cli`, there is `.angular-cli.json` file.

In json file, within `apps` you can add `styles` and `scripts` you want to load from `node_modules` folder.

For example, in my project to add I have added `font-awesome.scss`, `bootstrap.scss` and scripts like `jquery tether and bootstrap` like this.

```
"apps": [
    {

      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
        "styles.scss"
      ],

      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ],

  ],
```

Comment: Using Angular CLI might be an option, however JHipster projects do not contain a `.angular-cli.json` per default. I would rather do without that and work with what the template already offers.