# Using Third Party NPM packages in Angular-Cli

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-cli

I have read countless tutorials on how to use third party packages but none actually say what needs to happen in the `component.ts` to make things work in regards to the import statement and how to get access to the function.

package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vote539/excel-as-json

Here are the steps I followed:

- 1) Npm Install excel-as-json --save
- 2) Add script to angluar-cli.json scripts array
- 3) Add typings in typings.d.ts
- 4) Add import statesments

## 1) Using Angular-Cli I installed the package

I have added this package to my scripts array inside `angular-cli.json`.

## 2) .Angular-Cli.json

```
...
  "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [ "../node_modules/excel-as-json/lib/excel-as-json.js" ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
...
```

## 3) I added in some typings

## typings.d.ts

```
declare var module: {
  id: string;
};
declare var require: any;
```

## 4) Inside my component.ts file I have added in the import statement

`convertExcel = require('excel-as-json').processFile;`

and then in my constructor I added in the code needed to run the conversion:

## compoent.ts

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{ 
  constructor() {
    convertExcel('../assets/excel/assignedresources.xlsx', '../assets/excel/assignedresources.json');
   }

    ngOnInit() {

      }
  }
```

I tried many various of the import state, Always getting the following errors:

## errors

```
Cannot find module 'excel-as-json'.)
(14,5): Cannot find name 'convertExcel'.)
```

Comment: Possible equivalent of how to use third party JS in Angular take a look at this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45387777/2708210)

Comment: i would suggest if you are not sure of typings dnt go for it . More on [that](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)