# Angular4 pop up is closing if user click out side the pop up?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I followed this tutorial for pop up modal in angular4:

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/01/24/angular-2-custom-modal-window-dialog-box

If I click outside of the modal, the modal disappears. But I do not want the modal to disappear until user clicks the close icon.

Here is the modal's `OnInit`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        let modal = this;

        // ensure id attribute exists
        if (!this.id) {
            console.error('modal must have an id');
            return;
        }

        // move element to bottom of page (just before </body>) so it can be displayed above everything else
        this.element.appendTo('body');

        // close modal on background click
        this.element.on('click', function (e: any) {
            var target = $(e.target);
            if (!target.closest('.modal-body').length) {
                modal.close();
            }
        });

        // add self (this modal instance) to the modal service so it's accessible from controllers
        this.modalService.add(this);
    }
```

Here is the plunker of what I have actually:
   https://plnkr.co/edit/gPCTvV?p=preview

Comment: Using JQuery inside angular for such a thing is not a good practice, I wouldn't recommend this tutorial :/

Comment: Supamiu I am new to angular, can you please tell me why it's not a good practice to use jquey inside angular

Comment: Because JQuery does what angular can already do, and in a better way.

Comment: Ok , can you suggest any solution for pop-ups in angula2/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove this from the `app/_directives/modal.component.ts`

```
    // close modal on background click
    this.element.on('click', function (e: any) {
        var target = $(e.target);
        if (!target.closest('.modal-body').length) {
            modal.close();
        }
    });
```

Updated Plunker [LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/ytI3Cj?p=preview)

**Update**

You can make use of material dialogue or make use of bootstrap modal.

For material dialogue live example check this working [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts) and click on contact.

Also you can check this [angular materail link](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

For your purpose where you don't want the modal to be closed when clicked outside check out this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vhyIwI9XxiIz221qLlCU?p=preview).

to use bootstrap modal check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45387777/2708210) it has a working demo too

Comment: Thanks, you really save my time

Comment: Is there any better solution without using jquery

Comment: No, I do n't want use use material, I am using bootstrap3+ angular4