# Can't use ng2-bootstrap-modal in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use ng2-bootstrap-modal in Angular 4 and ASP NET 5(VS 2017).
I've followed instructions provided [there](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap-modal):

In systemjs.config.js I've added:

```
map: {....
       'ng2-bootstrap-modal': 'npm:ng2-bootstrap-modal',
...
 packages: {
            ....
            'ng2-bootstrap-modal': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
        }
```

But,after importing in app.module:

```
...
import { BootstrapModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap-modal';
....
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
   ....
    BootstrapModalModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

my app doesn't start,in console I have:

```
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (403 Forbidden) loading 
http://localhost:3590/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap-modal
```

thanks

**EDIT:**
I've found this [plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/MB6NnzfhicMyAiMJy6YM?p=preview) and I've updated my systemjs.config.js(see it above),now the erorr is

```
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (403 Forbidden) loading http://localhost:3590/node_modules/rxjs
```

Comment: you can directly use modal in angular 4 with out using any extension [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45387777/2708210)

Comment: do you use angular-cli?

Comment: @Rahul: I'm trying to have a reusable bootstrap confirm component,that seems to have what I'm looking for

Comment: You can have that modal as a component there and re use it depends actually. I thought that might help

Comment: I'm new to Angular so I don't know how to create a component that I can subscipe to it in order to get response as I've seen there: `showConfirm() {
    this.dialogService.addDialog(ConfirmComponent, {
      title:'Confirmation',
      message:'Bla bla confirm some action?'})
      .subscribe((isConfirmed)=>{
        //Get dialog result
        this.confirmResult = isConfirmed;
    });
  }`

Comment: @ federico  I'm using Angular integrated with Visual Studio,I don't think is angular-cli

Comment: I've edit my first post,added plnkr example and the new error message.thanks

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: I have a portable teamviewer installed

Comment: You will not get the above error if you  use the config they've shared

Comment: Indeed using that configuration it is working,thanks for the tip