# How to integrate bootstrap-treeview in an Angular-app?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, treeview

How do I make bootstrap-treeview visible in an angular 4 project?

I am developing an Angular front-end and my first step is to integrate a bootstrap-treeview in a component.

I have added bootstrap-treeview.min.css, jquery.js and bootstrap-treeview.min.js in the angular-cli.json, then I put the referenced script-files and css files in the assets-directory.

I have followed the instructions of [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GWz9UmFvPU).

`ng build` and `ng serve` compiles without errors, but the treeview is not visible in the component.

When I open the relevant component.html in a browser the treeview is visible and works to this point. I can expand the dropdown-list with the childs and select a link.  But when I start the app by `ng serve` the component is empty.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var jquery: any;
declare var $: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-document-tree',
  templateUrl: './document-tree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./document-tree.component.css']
})
export class DocumentTreeComponent implements OnInit {
  
  
  ngOnInit() {     
  }  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/bootstrap-treeview.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Tree-Component</h3>
    <table border="5px" height="300px" width="200px">
        <tr border="5px">
            <td border="5px">
                <div class="container" border="5px" height="600px" width="200px" >
                    <div id="tree" class="treeview" height="600px" width="200px" >

                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <!--  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="../../../assets/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myTree = [
            {
                text: "Parent 1",
                nodes: [
                    {
                        text: "Child 1",
                        nodes: [
                            {
                                text: "Grandchild 1"
                            },
                            {
                                text: "Grandchild 2"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Child 2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: "Parent 2"
            },
            {
                text: "Parent 3"
            },
            {
                text: "Parent 4"
            },
            {
                text: "Parent 5"
            }
        ];

        $('#tree').treeview({ data: myTree });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are doing it wrong you need to import it like a third party js in angular . check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45387777/2708210) . here i am importing bootstrap modal same way you need to add tree view