# Hook to bootstrap 4 modal show / hide events from Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Having a modal with id `myModal` I'm trying to hook up to events when it shows and closes. Following the documentation of https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#events I have added the following to my modal component:

```
this.modalElement = document.getElementById("myModal");
this.modalElement.addEventListener("hidden.bs.modal", this.onModalHidden);
this.modalElement.addEventListener("shown.bs.modal", this.onModalShown);
```

The event handlers for now will only console.log "shown" or "hidden" to test but unfortunately I can't get it to work:

```
private onModalShown = (event) => {
    console.log("modal is shown!!!");
}
```

Is there something missing and is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: I think it's better for you to use bootstrap for angular - https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Comment: do you have open and close button for the modal ? then you can hook up using button clicks . Are you not able to hook a bootstrap modal to angular ts ? If you are looking to hook up a modal to angular using only bootstrap check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45387777/2708210

Comment: I could use NgB but I wanted to stick to the original bootstrap if that was possible. I don't really have a close button because it's an image that is displayed in the modal (maybe is not the best thing to do but I thought it could work)

Comment: Well there are a lot of reasons why this is a bad practice... Don't do unecessary direct calls to the DOM elements.http://angularjs.blogspot.fr/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html

Answer (score 7):

You can subscribe to `onOpen` and `onDismiss` events in ModalComponent.

```
@ViewChild('yourModal')
yourModal: ModalComponent;
```

I suggest you to subscribe to those events in `ngAfterViewInit`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.yourModal.onOpen.subscribe(() => {
   //do something
 });

 this.yourModal.onDismiss.subscribe(() => {
   //do something
 });
}
```

Comment: this is very clean approach. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may try these code snippets:

First, I used ViewChild directive to call my modal.

```
    @ViewChild('MyModal') mymodal: ElementRef;

    //show
    $(this.mymodal.nativeElement).modal('show');
    //hide
    $(this.mymodal.nativeElement).modal('hide');

    //catch the event when modal is hidden
    //trigger implicity hide when backdrop is clicked or esc keypress
    // i had issues on closing modals and this fixed the problem
    $(this.mymodal.nativeElement).on('hidden.bs.modal',  () => {
        $(this).modal('hide');
        this.cancelProcedure();//my internal reset function
    });
```

Comment: This was a great start, just missing that this needs to be wrapped in an AfterViewInit in order for it to work.