# Typescript catch bootstrap 4 modal open event

Tags: jquery, html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am trying to execute some code when the bootstrap model opens but everything i try isn't working.
Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mobileModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" >
```

Typescript:

```
@ViewChild('mobileModal') mobileModal: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.mobileModal.nativeElement).on('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
      console.log("TESTTESTTEST")
    });
    $(this.mobileModal.nativeElement).on('shown.bs.modal', () => {
      console.log("TESTTESTTEST")
    });
    $("#mobileModal").on('shown', function () {
      console.log("TESTTESTTEST")
    });
  }
```

Other questions i  looked at but didnt work:

[Hook to bootstrap 4 modal show / hide events from Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922427/hook-to-bootstrap-4-modal-show-hide-events-from-typescript)

[Capture close event on Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298041/capture-close-event-on-bootstrap-modal)

[Calling a function on bootstrap modal open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461682/calling-a-function-on-bootstrap-modal-open/17461707)

Comment: Why use jQuery with angular?

Comment: Cause i was giving that a shot do you know how to catch that event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Hostlistener with angular directive.

```
@HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event'])
onMouseEnter(event: any) {    
 // Logs the id of the element 
 // where the event is originally invoked.     
 console.log(event.target.id);
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bacon-ipsum?file=app%2Fonly-my-pork.directive.ts)